# Issue in run the sqldeveloper in terminal

Tags: java, jdk, oracle, jre, sqldeveloper

I am facing the issue during run the sqldevleoper in the terminal, for that installed JDK 1.8 in my machine even though it showing like.  Please refer the below error and share your solution to that.

```
Error: Java home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0 is not a JDK,
either jre/bin/java OR lib/tools.jar OR lib/dt.jar is missing.
Running SQL Developer under a JRE is not supported.

If this Java VM is actually a full JDK installation, add
SetSkipJ2SDKCheck true to one of the following files.
Otherwise specify a different Java JDK location with a
SetJavaHome directive in one of the following files:
/home/msr/.sqldeveloper/4.2.0/product.conf
/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
```

Comment: How did you install SQL Developer? What's the output of `dpkg-query -l openjdk-\*-jre-headless`, `echo "$JAVA_HOME"`, `readlink -f "$(which java)"` and `update-alternatives --display java`?